# How Random module get tested in OCaml?

Tags: random, ocaml

OCaml has a [`Random` module](http://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/random.ml), I am wondering how it tests itself for randomness. However, i don't have a clue what exactly they are doing. I understand it tries to test for `chi-square` with two more dependencies tests. Here are the code for the testing part:

**chi-square test**

```
(* Return the sum of the squares of v[i0,i1[ *)
let rec sumsq v i0 i1 =
  if i0 >= i1 then 0.0
  else if i1 = i0 + 1 then Pervasives.float v.(i0) *. Pervasives.float v.(i0)
  else sumsq v i0 ((i0+i1)/2) +. sumsq v ((i0+i1)/2) i1
;;

let chisquare g n r =
  if n <= 10 * r then invalid_arg "chisquare";
  let f = Array.make r 0 in
  for i = 1 to n do
    let t = g r in
    f.(t) <- f.(t) + 1
  done;
  let t = sumsq f 0 r
  and r = Pervasives.float r
  and n = Pervasives.float n in
  let sr = 2.0 *. sqrt r in
  (r -. sr,   (r *. t /. n) -. n,   r +. sr)
;;
```

**Q1:**, why they write `sum of squares` like that?

It seems it is just summing up all squares. Why not write like:

```
let rec sumsq v i0 i1 =
  if i0 >= i1 then 0.0
  else Pervasives.float v.(i0) *. Pervasives.float v.(i0) + (sumsq v (i0+1) i1)
```

**Q2:**, why they seem to use different way for chisquare?

From the [chi squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test) wiki, they formula is

[image]

But it seems they are using different formula, what's behind the scene?

---

**Other two dependencies tests**

```
(* This is to test for linear dependencies between successive random numbers.
*)
let st = ref 0;;
let init_diff r = st := int r;;
let diff r =
  let x1 = !st
  and x2 = int r
  in
  st := x2;
  if x1 >= x2 then
    x1 - x2
  else
    r + x1 - x2
;;

let st1 = ref 0
and st2 = ref 0
;;

(* This is to test for quadratic dependencies between successive random
   numbers.
*)
let init_diff2 r = st1 := int r; st2 := int r;;
let diff2 r =
  let x1 = !st1
  and x2 = !st2
  and x3 = int r
  in
  st1 := x2;
  st2 := x3;
  (x3 - x2 - x2 + x1 + 2*r) mod r
;;
```

**Q3:** I don't really know these two tests, can someone en-light me?

Comment: Is it odd that the ocaml testsuite doesn't use these tests?

Comment: @nlucaroni it is in `Random.ml` file

Comment: I know. I'm just thinking out loud why they wouldn't be run on a regular basis and put in the ocaml/testsuite files (https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/testsuite/tests/lib-random)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:**

It's a question of memory usage. You will notice that for large arrays, your implementation of sumsq will fail with *"Stack overflow during evaluation"* (on my laptop, it fails for r = 200000). This is because before adding `Pervasives.float v.(i0) *. Pervasives.float v.(i0)` to `(sumsq v (i0+1) i1)`, you have to compute the latter. So it's not until you have computed the result of the last call of sumsq that you can start "going up the stack" and adding everything. Clearly, sumsq is going to be called r times in your case, so you will have to keep track of r calls.

By contrast, with their approach they only have to keep track of log(r) calls because once sumsq has been computed for half the array, you only need to the result of the corresponding call (you can forget about all the other calls that you had to do to compute that).

However, there are other ways of achieving this result and I'm not sure why they chose this one (maybe somebody will be able to tell ?). If you want to know more on the problems linked to recursion and memory, you should probably check [the wikipedia article on tail-recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). If you want to know more on the technique that they used here, you should check [the wikipedia article on divide and conquer algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) -- be careful though, because here we are talking about memory and the Wikipedia article will probably talk a lot about temporal complexity (speed).

**Q2:**

You should look more closely at both expressions. Here, all the E_i's are equal to n/r. If you replace this in the expression you gave, you will find the same expression that they use: `(r *. t /. n) -. n`. I didn't check about the values of the bounds though, but since you have a Chi-squared distribution with parameter r-minus-one-or-two degrees of freedom, and r quite large, it's not surprising to see them use this kind of confidence interval. The Wikipedia article you mentionned should help you figure out what confidence interval they use exactly fairly easily.

Good luck!

**Edit:** Oops, I forgot about **Q3**. I don't know these tests either, but I'm sure you should be able to find more about them by googling something like "linear dependency between consecutive numbers" or something. =)

**Edit 2:** In reply to Jackson Tale's June 29 question about the confidence interval:

They should indeed test it against the Chi-squared distribution -- or, rather, use the Chi-squared distribution to find a confidence interval. However, because of the central limit theorem, the Chi-squared distribution with *k* degrees of freedom converges to a normal law with mean *k* and variance *2k*. A classical result is that the 95% confidence interval for the normal law is approximately [μ - 1.96 σ, μ + 1.96 σ], where μ is the mean and σ the standard deviation -- so that's roughly the mean ± twice the standard deviation. Here, the number of degrees of freedom is (I think) *r - 1 ~ r* (because *r* is large) so that's why I said I wasn't surprised by a confidence interval of the form [*r* - 2 sqrt(*r*), *r* + 2 sqrt(*r*)]. Nevertheless, now that I think about it I can't see why they don't use ± 2 sqrt(2 *r*)... But I might have missed something. And anyway, even if I was correct, since sqrt(2) > 1, they get a more stringent confidence interval, so I guess that's not really a problem. But they should document what they're doing a bit more... I mean, the tests that they're using are probably pretty standard so most likely most people reading their code will know what they're doing, but still...

Also, you should note that, as is often the case, this kind of test is not conclusive: generally, you want to show that something has some kind of effect. So you formulate two hypothesis : the null hypothesis, "there is no effect", and the alternative hypothesis, "there is an effect". Then, you show that, given your data, the probability that the null hypothesis holds is very low. So you conclude that the alternative hypothesis is (most likely) true -- i.e. that there *is* some kind of effect. This is conclusive. Here, what we would like to show is that the random number generator is good. So we don't want to show that the numbers it produces *differ* from some law, but that they *conform* to it. The only way to do that is to perform as many tests as possible showing that the number produced have the same property as randomly generated ones. But the only conclusion we can draw is "we were not able to find a difference between the actual data and what we would have observed, had they really been randomly generated". But this is not a lack of rigor from the OCaml developers: people always do that (eg, a lot of tests require, say, the normality. So before performing these tests, you try to find a test which would show that your variable is not normally distributed. And when you can't find any, you say "Oh well, the normality of this variable is probably sufficient for my subsequent tests to hold") -- simply because there is no other way to do it...

Anyway, I'm no statistician and the considerations above are simply my two cents, so you should be careful. For instance, I'm sure there is a better reason why they're using this particular confidence interval. I also think you should be able to figure it out if you write everything down carefully to make sure about what they're doing exactly.

Comment: Regarding your own question at the end of Q1, adding a set of positive floats by divide-and-conquer is more precise than adding them one by one. I cannot quantify how much more precise it is (it is obviously possible to build a counter-example where the one-by-one sum is exact and the divide-and-conquer is wrong), but intuitively, it is much better for a large majority of distributions.

Comment: one-by-one sum of sorted values with Kahan summation would be more accurate, no? Is there a measure of ulps on this method?

Comment: @nlucaroni the Wikipedia article on Kahan summation has a short discussion of it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm#Alternatives). Probably they didn't think the slight improvement in precision was enough to justify the big decrease in speed...

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh yes, that makes sense. Thanks a lot. However, in that case they are summing integers so I'm not sure why they convert them to floats during the computation -- I'm guessing they want to avoid integer overflow, but is there another reason?

Comment: Thanks! I should check wikipedia next time. That was my intuition though. I agree, the overhead is not worth it. I've been thinking about removing that summation from some software I wrote, but it gets compared to other software that uses it and i don't want users to get confused. Maybe this method would be a happy medium.

Comment: @bienvenu They want to avoid overflow and they are only interested in the value of the result up to some fixed relative accuracy. This is a textbook application of floating-point (but I am only guessing here, I don't know anything about randomness tests).

Comment: could you please explain more about the confidence interval they use, i.e., why `(r -. sr,   (r *. t /. n) -. n,   r +. sr)` is chosen to be the confidence interval? I thought if they get the chi-square x^2, they should check it against a distribution table?

Comment: @JacksonTale I've edited my post to "answer" your question about the confidence interval. However, this isn't really an answer since I don't really understand why they use this confidence interval. Also, Sorry for the late reply -- I hope you're still interested in the topic!